# mPDF Error: Doesn´t work on Server, alibaba

Tags: php, server, mpdf

I am using mPDF to create a pdf document and to save it. It works fine on my localhost but when I try it on the server it is not creating (Saving) the pdf document. Server Alibaba.
code here(php):

```
 ob_start();
require_once '../pdf/vendor/autoload.php';
$html = '<div>Hola</div>';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$css = file_get_contents('public/css/pdf.css');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($htmll);
$mpdf->Output('Servicio.pdf','D');
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: im betting your dont have the right write permissions set.

Comment: do you mean the permissions on the server?

Comment: The `D` mode means download, that is not a permissions issue. More likely HTTP headers are overriden somewhere along the way. Unless you really want to save the file to the server filesystem, then use `F` mode in the `Output method`. Is there by any chance some other error present?